# one align to equations inside align* and other align for intertext

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I want to get this output-same place where "=" for equations, and same place in "-" for lines of text inside intertext that describe the equations:

```
           z=a+b
         tbv=y*x
   First var z-the sum of ..
Second var tbv-the multiply of..
```

I try this code (add && where I need same place of the text), but this code not compile:

```
\begin{align*}
   z&=a+b\\
   tbv&=y*x
   \intertext{ First $z$ &&- the sum of ..\\ 
    Second $tbv$ &&- the multiply of..}
\end{align*}
```

In other words how can be done align for text(2 lines) inside intertext as is done for equation by "&", if it not possible with intertext then please give other way.

**Edit1- output should looks as the image below**
(@Werner image in comment)
[image]

**Edit2-** It can be done by:

```
\begin{align*}
   z&=a+b\\
   tbv&=y*x
\end{align*}

\vspace{-.5cm}
\begin{align*}
  \text{First }z &-\text{the sum of..}\\
  \text{Second }z &-\text{the sum of..}
\end{align*}
```

But this solution not works if the text longer then 1 line.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot but & inside  intertext

Comment: Thanks @dalief. I edit the question according your comment. Can you give other way to that?

Comment: I see no reason for introducing this type of alignment in a comment, so no. It us the type of thing one would write on a piece of paper or on a blackboard, imo it does not belong in printed form.

Comment: Are you interested in something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJHgB.png) (the vertical lines on the edge denote the text block boundaries).

Comment: @Werner, yes as the image that you attach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` to automatically put `<stuff>` in a box that is widest across the same `<tag>` (with the option of individually `<align>`ing each one to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}% To show the text block boundary

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     z &= a + b      \\
   tbv &= y \times x
\end{align*}

\noindent\eqmakebox[varexpl][r]{First $z$} - the sum of \ldots \par
\noindent\eqmakebox[varexpl][r]{Second $tbv$} - the multiplication of \ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: outside align* posible to do also in other ways, the main question here how to do more then one place (label) of align, one place(label) for equation, and another place for text lines.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah, sorry, that's not clear at all. You'll need to describe what you mean by "on place (label) of `align`, one place (label) for equation, and another place for text lines" by means of some examples/visuals.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `align*` inside `intertext` and set the required alignments. Also, `\shortintertext` from `mathtools` is better here.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   z   &= a+b \\
   tbv &= y*x \\
   \shortintertext{
     \begin{align*}
       \text{First }    z &\text{ - the sum of .. } \\ 
       \text{Second } tbv &\text{ - the multiplication of .. }
     \end{align*}
   }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why just not to do as I suggest in Edit2? Still my solution in Edit2 not elegant way to resolve the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `\intertext` is for, unless there is some other equation past it.

You want a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}% To show the text block boundary

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     z &= a + b      \\
   tbv &= y \times x
\shortintertext{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{} r@{ - }l @{}}
  First $z$ & the sum of \ldots \\
  Second $tbv$ & the multiplication of \ldots
  \end{tabular}%
}
    1  &= 2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For longer text, use `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text
\usepackage{showframe}% To show the text block boundary

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     z &= a + b      \\
   tbv &= y \times x
\shortintertext{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r@{ - }X @{}}
  First $z$ &
  \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
  Second $tbv$ &
  \lipsum[2][1-3]
  \end{tabularx}%
}
    1  &= 2
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your solution of tabular not work with text longer then 1 line ('..'-these dots mean that text is longer), looks that only solution is \eqmakebox that Werner is suggested.

Comment: @Ben I can't guess your intentions. Why not specifying it more clearly in the question? Anyway, you can consider `tabularx`. I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the text simply inside the `align*` environment using `\text{}` can produce the output.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   z   &= a+b \\
   tbv &= y*x \\
   \text{First var $z$} & \text{ - the sum of .. }\\
   \text{Second var $tbv$} & \text{ - the multiplication of .. }
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answer wrong, because you put "=" of equations, and "-" of text lines in same location.

Comment: @Ben Okay. I posted the answer based on the output you mentioned in the original question. I did not look into the answer posted by Werner.